# WPF Font Ms Gothic in .net 4.0 doesn't look the same in .net 3.0

Tags: wpf, fonts

I moved from .Net Framework 3.0 to 4.0 and the Japanese (and English as well) text became clear and lost weight 
I want it back as it was in .Net 3 
photo: new = .Net 4, old = .Net 3
[image]
I've followed [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx) trying to fix it but no success yet 
tried the following with different combinations:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" FontFamily="MS Gothic" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" FontFamily="MS Gothic" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" FontFamily="MS Gothic" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"/>
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a solution, but on Microsoft's forum, there was an answer that the thicker font display is "[caused by internal font optimization of WPF rendering system](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9d86e948-f47f-421d-ac38-fea1972ca614)" for two fonts, MS UI Gothic and Bold MS UI Gothic.

As there are no solutions suggested there, I assume that you can not avoid that optimization. If MS UI Gothic are not MUST for what you are making, you may use Meiryo or other Japanese fonts to work around it.

Comment: i want the thicker font , is there  way to reproduce it ?

Comment: well , no way is the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is also not a solution but I had a similar issue in that I wanted to use a particular font which was not available on Windows XP, but was in Vista and Win 7. I found an open source compatible font and included it as a resource in my application. This way I ensured that the application font looked the same across all versions of Windows.

You may be able to find a font that you could include in your application.